# Python 3 Couldn't open "<folderdirectoryhere>" : permission denied

Tags: image, python-3.x, tkinter

Hoi! I was trying to access an image of mine using the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
image = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\*<mynamehere>*\\Documents\\Platformer")
label = tk.Label(image=image)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But I got the error stated in the title.

What's wrong, and how can I fix it? Any tips to load images in the future?

Comment: Is it just a copy-paste error, but you only have one backslash between `Users` and `*<mynamehere>*`. Also, using forwardslashes is usually better overall, and not prone to forgetting to double-up.

Comment: Yes, that was an error, but even though I fixed it, the access is still denied?

Comment: Check if the file was open in any program. Sometimes the file will be locked if you open in some editors like MS office apps.

Answer (score 0):

put an "r" before the file to open the raw file

```
image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\\Users\*<mynamehere>*\\Documents\\Platformer")
```